# Image from Excel to vb.net Picturebox

Tags: vb.net, excel, image, picturebox

I have found many questions for the opposite vb.net to excel but none for getting a picture from an excel `cell(row,column)` into a picture box. My app is a template that gets strings of text from an excel file. Which works fine but now I am trying to also transfer pictures. I have tried `picSpindle.Image = shXL.Cells(19, 2).Value` but doesn't do anything. Does not error out though!

Will copy and paste work?

Code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    Dim appXL As Excel.Application
    Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook
    Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim raXL As Excel.Range
    Dim PartID As String
    Dim RefCard As String

    Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
        'Dispaly Brembo Logo
        picLogo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Read File Source with part number ******************Example From TXT
        PartID = ("19.N111.10")

        ' Start Excel and get Application object.
        appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        appXL.Visible = False

        'Open Reference Card*************************************************************************************

        wbXl = appXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Visual Studios Projects\Reference Card App\" & PartID & ".xlsx")
        shXL = wbXl.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' Copys Reference Card Text from Cells To App labels
        lblCODE.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 9).Value
        Debug.Print(lblCODE.Text)
        lblREV.Text = shXL.Cells(3, 13).Value
        lblDate.Text = shXL.Cells(5, 9).Value
        lblCustomer.Text = shXL.Cells(8, 2).Value
        lblPart.Text = shXL.Cells(11, 2).Value
        lblSpindleType.Text = shXL.Cells(15, 2).Value
        lblPaintType.Text = shXL.Cells(7, 6).Value
        lblDunnageType.Text = shXL.Cells(8, 8).Value
        lblPartsLayer.Text = shXL.Cells(11, 11).Value
        lblLayers.Text = shXL.Cells(15, 11).Value
        lblTotalParts.Text = shXL.Cells(20, 11).Value
        lblPackagingInstructs.Text = shXL.Cells(20, 11).Value
     'Works up to here!

        ' Copys Reference Card Pictures from Cells To App Pictureboxs
        picSpindle.Image = shXL.Cells(19, 2).Value
        picRotorTop.Image = shXL.Cells(10, 6).Value
        picRotorBottom.Image = shXL.Cells(19, 6).Value
        picDunnageFinal.Image = shXL.Cells(10, 8).Value
        picDunnageLayer.Image = shXL.Cells(19, 8).Value


        ' Close objects
        raXL = Nothing
        shXL = Nothing
        wbXl = Nothing
        appXL.Quit()
        appXL = Nothing
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shXL.Cells(19, 2).Value
```

and so on won't work because pictures aren't store in `cells` but over them
meaning `values` of these `cells` will be `nothing`

try these links

[1](http://tips-testing.blogspot.com/2008/08/vba-extract-pictures-from-excel.html)

[2](http://www.howtodothings.com/computers-internet/how-to-extract-pictures-from-an-excel-file)

[3](http://www.expertsupdates.com/excel-macro-articles/extract-images-from-excel-worksheet-macro-16.aspx)

Comment: I decided to just leave the pictures in a folder along with the excel file with the text strings. I thought you could copy the pictures by cell because if you record a macro in excel and do a cell copy and paste it works. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

The images are not inside a cell. But the coordinates of the top left corner point to a cell, with this code above you can make your own function that searches through images.

You can do so:

```
    shXL = wbXl.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' # Loop for all Shapes 
    ' But I don't know what other controls over 
    '    the images are considered "shapes",
    '    Perhaps the best way is to verify that 
    '    in the "clipboard" there is truly a picture
    For i = 0 To shXL.Shapes.Count - 1

        'THIS IS THE MAIN POINT

        ' # get the pictures and copy to clipboard
        'shXL.Shapes.Item(i).Copy()

        ' # paste the picture in the pictureBox from clipboard
        'PictureBox1.Image = Clipboard.GetImage

        'AND OTHER PROPERTIS

        MsgBox(shXL.Shapes.Item(i).Name) ' the name in excel
        MsgBox(shXL.Shapes.Item(i).AlternativeText) 'the name of the file
        MsgBox(shXL.Shapes.Item(i).TopLeftCell.Column) 'the column position (of the top left corner)
        MsgBox(shXL.Shapes.Item(i).TopLeftCell.Row) 'the row position (of the top left corner)
        MsgBox(shXL.Shapes.Item(i).Width) 'the with in px
        MsgBox(shXL.Shapes.Item(i).Height) 'the height in px
        MsgBox(shXL.Shapes.Item(i).Top) 'the top in px
        MsgBox(shXL.Shapes.Item(i).Left) 'the left in px
    Next
```